# How can I set the height proportionate to the window size in TailWind?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am trying to create a banner using an image. The issue I have is that when I use the inbuilt `h-*` utility in Tailwind, it renders extremely small.

```
<div class="hidden sm:block">
    <img
        class="w-full h-20 object-cover object-center"
        src="https://scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s1080x1080/123373127_3521914557896505_7295974815335315741_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=109&_nc_ohc=DK6qb5zEM4MAX_DFVAe&_nc_tp=15&oh=271f24ef76f786772b436b59b9bd4e6b&oe=5FCC2E33"
    />
</div>
```

Below is the output that is given from this code.

[image: Distorted Image]

Any help on how I can reduce the size, without it distorting to a suitable banner size (roughly 200px) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What's the target size for your banner? By using the `h-20` class you've made it [80px high](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/height#app). If you want it to be full-width and around 200px high, you can try `h-48` (translates to 12rem) instead, see https://play.tailwindcss.com/FD72cGTIgx